# Problem with EOF when determining stream end

Tags: c++, c, io, eof

When I try to determine end of file with function `feof(FILE *)`, I find it does not work as I expected: an extra read is required even if the stream does end. E.g., `feof(FILE*)` will not return true if invoked on a file with 10 bytes data just after reading 10 bytes out. I need an extra read operation which of course returns 0. Then `feof(FILE *)` will say "OK, now you reach the end."

Why is one more `read` required and how can I determine end of file or how can I know how many bytes are left in a file stream if I don't want the `feof`-style?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, is "while( !feof( ... ) )" always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/in-c-is-while-feof-always-wrong)

Comment: Think of a stream as water behind a tap. When you want something *(a char: `getchar()`, a line: `fgets()`, a bunch of data: `fread()`, ...)* you open the tap, get what you want, and close the tap. If it worked you can't know if there is more water; or if the tap is going to break next. If it failed, you can determine **why** it failed: because there was not enough water (`feof` is true); or because the tap broke (`ferror` is true).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use feof() or any variants—it is as simple as that. You want it to somehow predict the next read will fail, but that's not what it does - it tells you what the result of the *previous* read was. The correct way to read a file is (in pseudocode):

```cpp
while(read(file, buffer)) {
   // Do something with buffer
}
```

In other words, you need to test the result of the read operation. This is true for both C streams and C++ iostreams.

Comment: And if you really need to look ahead, with iostreams you can use `peek`.

Comment: `feof` is useful, but not for what OP wants. The use is testing to see if a read failure was due to EOF or read error.