# Reading a Linux device with fstream

Tags: c++, usb, linux-device-driver, fstream

I'm attempting to get feedback from some hardware that is used over [USBTMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes) and [SCPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments).

I can read and write to the device using `/dev/usbtmc0` in a C++ [io]fstream, alternating by reading and writing to send and receive messages. Most commands are terminated by a single newline, so it's easy to tell when the end of a response is received. The simplified code I'm using for that is:

```
fstream usb;
usb.open("/dev/usbtmc0", fstream::in);
if (usb.good())
{
    string output;
    getline(usb, output);
    usb.close();
    // Do things with output
}
// Additional cleanup code...
```

There is, however, one thing that is escaping me, and it's defined in the SCPI/IEEE specification as "*LRN?". When sent, the connected device will send back arbitrary data (actual wording from the specification) that can be used to later reprogram the device should it get into a weird state.

The issue with the response message of this LRN command is that it contains one or more newlines. It does properly terminate the entire message with a newline, but the fact that there are newlines embedded makes it really tricky to work with. Some hardware will prefix the payload with a length, but some don't.

When reading data from the hardware, there is a 5 second timeout built into the Linux *usbtmc* kernel driver that will block any read calls if you try to read past what's available.

Using fstream::eof doesn't seem to return anything useful. It acts much like a socket. Is there a way that I can read all data on the device without knowing about its length, termination, and while avoiding a kernel timeout?

Comment: Possibly this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029875/problem-with-eof-when-determine-stream-end/6029898#6029898 might shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `fstream` for this is that `fstream` has internal buffering, there's no 1:1 correlation between device `fileOps->read` calls and `fstream` operations.

For interacting with device drivers, you really need to use the low-level `open`, `read`, `write` functions from `unistd.h` and `fcntl.h`.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't really consider the buffering. I'll give this a go tomorrow and see how things go.

Comment: This ended up being a part of the problem. The other part was that the usbtmc driver in mainline doesn't set the EOF bit, so the read will always stall. Otherwise, this worked out. :)